# array_sum и string

Tags: php

Существует код

```
                        $sum = $resULT2ati['OCENKA']['VALUE'];
                        //echo $sum;
                        $suma = array_sum( explode( ',', $sum ) );
                        echo $suma;
```

Выводит не сумму, а просто строку по типу "554555" (это и есть те самые числа которые должны суммироваться), как решить?

Comment: Покажите что в `$sum`. А также полный код. Может у вас там цикл?

Comment: привести элементы массива к целочисленному типу

Comment: @ПавелЕриков они и так должны просуммироваться, даже если они в строке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский

Да действительно есть цикл, нужно значения вывести в массив и после за цикл?

Comment: @АндрейКотов Я не знаю вашей конечной цели) Может и надо) Нужно весь код видеть и знать что вы хотите в итоге получить. А так - приведённый код вполне рабочий

Comment: @АлексейШиманский"554555" - это должно стать 5+5+4+5+5+5=сума
Такова цель )

Comment: @АндрейКотов так у вас там между числами нет запятой) explode не отрабатывает в итоге. Нужно, чтобы между числами обязательно был разделитель в таком случае, чтобы понимать по чему делить/разделять

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А как его можно поместить в такую строку? :о

Comment: @АндрейКотов ну я не знаю как вы эту строку формируете. При формировании добавляйте разделитель

Answer (score -1):

Приведи типы в зависимости от типа, который ты хочешь складывать. Пример сложения целых чисел:

```
$sum = $resULT2ati['OCENKA']['VALUE'];
//echo $sum;
$suma = array_sum( explode( ',', (int)$sum ) );
echo $suma;
```

Answer (score -2):

[**str_split**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php) — Преобразует строку в массив

```
 $sum = $resULT2ati['OCENKA']['VALUE']; 

 $suma = array_sum(str_split($sum)); 

 echo $suma;
```

**[preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)** — Разбивает строку по регулярному выражению

```
   $sum = $resULT2ati['OCENKA']['VALUE']; 

    $suma = array_sum( preg_split('//', $sum, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

    echo $suma;
```

Comment: а зачем тут preg-split? В целом ответ верно-неверный. А всё потому, что некорректно разбивать строку по символам в текущем случае, т.к. числа могут быть длиной и не 1 символ, т.е. 55, 45.

Comment: Алексей, в теории да, но тогда теряется смысл задания считать их сумму.
При наличии двух и более разрядных чисел стоит всё-таки задуматься о раздлителе и воспользоваться  функцией expode

Comment: Да, я думаю более корректно направить человека на эту стезю)